# Nested observable in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a self describing definition as follows:

```
var my_data = {
  types: { typeA: {fieldX: { type: "string"}},
           typeB: {fieldY: { type: "string"}} },
  entries: [{ type: "typeA", fieldX: "foo" },
            { type: "typeB", fieldY: "bar" }]
  };
```

The idea being that 'types' describes the data presented for each index of 'entries'.  This data is used to render a form for editing JSON data via a RESTful interface (an input for each type described field with bindings to the entry's field value).

I'm trying to set up a form in knockout which allows the 'entries' to be edited.  I first create the HTML which creates a select box for determining type.  To do this I map the types dictionary to an array:

```
function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then the KnockoutJS code to display the entries

```
<!-- ko foreach: entries -->
            <select data-bind="options: editTestViewModel.types,
                               optionsText: 'key',
                               optionsValue: 'value',
                               value: type,
                               event: { change: editTestViewModel.drawType }"></select>
            <div data-bind="attr: { id: $index() + 'typeFields' }" class="container"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The model view:

```
function EditTestViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.entries = ko.observableArray();
    self.types = ko.observable();

    self.setTest = function(test) {
        self.test = test;
        self.types(mapDictionaryToArray(test.types()));
        self.entries(ko.mapping.fromJS(test.entries(), self.stateMapping)());

    };

    self.editTest = function() {
        $('#edit').modal('hide');
        testsViewModel.edit(self.test, {
            entries: self.entries() ,
            types: self.types()
        });
    };

    self.drawType = function(place) {
        home = $('#typeFields');
        home.children().remove();
        for (var field in place.type) {
            tag = $('<div class="input-group">').appendTo(home);
            $('<span class="input-group-addon">' + field + '</span>').appendTo(tag);
            $('<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text: \'test\'">').appendTo(tag);
        }
    };

    self.stateMapping = {
        'type': {
            create: function(options) {
                return options.data
            }
        }
    }
}

var editTestViewModel = new EditTestViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(editTestViewModel, $('#edit')[0]);
```

The problem I am having is that the inserted data does not appear to be processed by KockoutJS.  The type select functions and populates the relevant fields but, the field value is not populated (static "test" for now).  Is KnockoutJS even supported for dynamically inserted content, and if so am I attempting to bind this correctly?

Comment: I would say that what you're attempting is certainly possible with knockout.  I'm not sure trying to dynamically insert html in this way is the right way to go about it though - have you considered using [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) at all?

Comment: What James said, have you considered templates? You should not have any HTML in your Javascript if you do it properly. You can very easily use foreach with knockout in your html templates! Just check it out!

Comment: OP: *Is KnockoutJS even supported for dynamically inserted content, and if so am I attempting to bind this correctly?* -> KnockoutJS is **meant** for this, and by using jQuery for performing DOM manipulation you are changing the view of your model without Knockout knowing.

Comment: I would help, but I can't figure out what kind of structure you want with the limited `data` sample and no visual preview. Perhaps you should make a fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to templates (still getting the hang of Knockout).  I made a fiddle here http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhwpn6dy/2/

I'm still stuck on the issue of updating the view when the 'type' select is changed.  I think I want an observable on entry.type but, I'm not sure how to best generate the observable for each entry.  Would it make sense to inherit a new class from ko.observableArray to inject this in each entry?  The mapping plugin looks good but I can't figure out how to make it generate two object properties (one a computed observable so that select still works).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for comments on the OP.

I rewrote to use templates.  For some reason I was under the impression that observables could not be used for option.value storage.  That appears to not be the case (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27873057/1440598).  In the constructor I now set the type to be an observable for each entry.

Changing the select triggers the template field update: 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhwpn6dy/3/

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="text: data.test"></div>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'entry-template', foreach: entries, as: 'entry' }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="entry-template">
    <h3 data-bind = "text: entry.type">I'm an entry</h3>
    <select data-bind="options: $root.type_keys,
                       optionsText: 'key',
                       optionsValue: 'key',
                       value: entry.type"></select>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-template', foreach: $root.fieldList(entry), as: 'field' }"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="field-template">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: field"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="attr: { 'aria-label': field }, value: entry[field]"/>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var data = {
    types: {
        typeA: {
            fieldX: {
                type: "string"
            }
        },
        typeB: {
            fieldY: {
                type: "string"
            }
        }
    },
    entries: [{
        type: "typeA",
        fieldX: "foo"
    }, {
        type: "typeB",
        fieldY: "bar"
    }],
    test: "Hello"
};

function MainViewModel(data_obj) {
    var self = this;

    self.data = data_obj;
    self.type_keys = mapDictionaryToArray(data_obj.types);    

    for (var entry in data_obj.entries) {
        data_obj.entries[entry].type = ko.observable(data_obj.entries[entry].type);
    }
    self.entries = ko.observableArray(data_obj.entries);
    console.log(self.entries());
}

MainViewModel.prototype.fieldList = function (entry) {
    var self = this;
    var keys = [];

    for (var key in self.data.types[entry.type()]) {
        if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }

    <!-- console.log(entry.type); -->
    return keys;
};

function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] });
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var dataViewModel = new MainViewModel(data);

ko.applyBindings(dataViewModel);
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured :)